# Save Nested JSON Parsed from XML to MongoDB

Tags: json, xml, node.js, mongodb, nested

I'm just starting out with the `MEAN stack` and I'm having trouble saving my parsed `JSON` into `Mongoose`. Here's my json parsing function:

```
function xmlToJson(url, callback) {
    var req = http.get(url, function(res) {
    var xml = '';

    // Create the listener for data being returned
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        xml += chunk;
    });

    res.on('error', function(e) {
        callback(e, null);
    });

    res.on('timeout', function(e) {
        callback(e, null);
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
            callback(null, result);
        });
    });
    });
}
```

I then try to save parsed data to Mongoose like this:

```
function saveToDB() {
    xmlToJson(url, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.err(err);
    }

    var json = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    // console.log(json);
    });

    db.collection('pools').insert(data, function(error, record) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log("data saved");
    });
}

saveToDB();
```

I keep getting `TypeError: undefined is not a function.` I know that this is because data is an `undefined` type (I tried logging `typeof data`), but I don't know why it's undefined, and I don't know how to fix it. I've tried using `JSON.parse(data)`, but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: can you check the output of  JSON.stringify(data, null, 2); ?

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` must have a callstack underneath with the line number of the offeding code, so you donj't have to guess whether it's `data`. And actually if `undefined is not a function` is the error, it must be that something is being *invoked as a function*, and *that* something is undefined.

Comment: Thanks! console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) correctly logs the XML file in JSON format. "db.collection('pools').insert(data, function(error, record)" is the exact line that's giving me the TypeError. Does this mean that insert is somehow undefined? I set up my database on MongoLabs, and added the pools collection from there (through the web browser).

Comment: There are two function calls on that line `.collection(…)` and `.insert(…)` so could be either of them. There should be more information displayed with the error, including the column number, [like this](http://i.imgur.com/UzSkHqa.png), which should tell you more. If it's indeed the `.collection(…)` that's undefined, the problem is obviously with your `db` object.

Comment: @laggingreflex Thanks for your help! I've managed to get everything working now. Turns out "data" wasn't the correct type, so insert wasn't being recognized as a proper function.